# how do closures work inside addEventListener?

Tags: javascript

I got this code:

```js
function getElementByName(name) {
  return document.querySelector(name);
}

function removeButton(parentToClick) {
  parentToClick.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let buttonToClick = e.target;

    const removeButton = getElementByName(`.remove`);

    removeButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
      console.log(e.target);
      remove(buttonToClick);
    });
  });
}

function remove(buttonToClick) {
  return buttonToClick.remove();
}

removeButton(getElementByName(`#menu`));
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <button data-action="save">Save</button>
  <button data-action="load">Load</button>
  <button data-action="search">Search</button>
</div>

<button class="remove">Remove</button>
```

When I click on the "remove" button the previous clicked one, for example, the *save* button, is taken from closure and then it's removed as expected. The problem is when I cliсk on another button, for instance, the *search* button and then click on the "remove" button, the closure has the *save* button rather than the *search* button. I'd like to know why it happens.

Comment: Do you realize you are binding multiple events to the remove button. So each click, you bind a new event listener, they are not replace the old ones....

Comment: Ummm ... you've explained exactly what happens in the code, and how the closures work, what is the question ..?

Comment: OK, do I have to move out the remove listener of the menu one?

Comment: Yes, and store the previously clicked menu button into a variable. Then check the stored element exists, and remove it if it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what happens:

1. You click on a search. It binds an event listener to remove.
2. You click on remove, it removes search from event listener in 1.
3. You click on save. It binds an event listener to remove.
4. You click on remove, it calls the event listener 1, and calls event listener from 3.

You are assuming that somehow the click event is only bound to that one element. The fact is you bound the click multiple times and it has no clue it is only supposed to be fired.

What can you do? Remove the event before binding another. Or better, store what is clicked and do not bind multiple events.

```js
function removeButton(parentToClick) {

  let buttonToClick = null;

  parentToClick.addEventListener('click', e => {
    buttonToClick = e.target.closest('button[data-action]');
  });

  const removeButton = document.querySelector('.remove');

  removeButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (buttonToClick) remove(buttonToClick);
    buttonToClick = null;
  });
}

function remove(buttonToClick) {
  return buttonToClick.remove();
}

removeButton(document.querySelector('#menu'));
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <button data-action="save">Save</button>
  <button data-action="load">Load</button>
  <button data-action="search">Search</button>
</div>

<button class="remove">Remove</button>
```